# Ansible not picking up proxy settings

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run an Ansible job on a remote host. But for that to happen, I need to go through a proxy.

Proxy server is: 142.133.134.161
Proxy port is: 1088

My playbook is simple for now:

```
---
- hosts: LAB1
  tasks:
    - name: Copy file
      template: src=/tmp/file1 dest=/tmp/file1
```

My environment file is:

```
[LAB1]
10.169.99.189
10.169.99.190
```

My `ansible.cfg` file is:

```
Host 10.169.99.*
  ProxyCommand nc -x 142.133.134.161:1088 %h %p
```

But when I run a job, it says "Connection timed out":

```
[root@vm1 ANSIBLE]# ansible -i /root/ANSIBLE/env/target LAB1 -m ping
10.169.99.190 | FAILED => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host 10.169.99.190 port 22: Connection timed out
    while connecting to 10.169.99.190:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
10.169.99.189 | FAILED => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host 10.169.99.189 port 22: Connection timed out
    while connecting to 10.169.99.189:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

When I run this in debug mode:

```
[root@vm1 ANSIBLE]# ansible -i /root/ANSIBLE/env/target LAB1 -m ping -vvvvv
<10.169.99.190> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: msdp
<10.169.99.190> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<10.169.99.189> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: msdp
<10.169.99.189> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<10.169.99.190> EXEC sshpass -d8 ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o User=msdp -o ConnectTimeout=10 10.169.99.190 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1473612082.62-116308097993503 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1473612082.62-116308097993503'
<10.169.99.189> EXEC sshpass -d9 ssh -C -tt -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath="/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o User=msdp -o ConnectTimeout=10 10.169.99.189 /bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1473612082.63-269107268980760 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1473612082.63-269107268980760'
10.169.99.189 | FAILED => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host 10.169.99.189 port 22: Connection timed out
    while connecting to 10.169.99.189:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
10.169.99.190 | FAILED => SSH Error: ssh: connect to host 10.169.99.190 port 22: Connection timed out
    while connecting to 10.169.99.190:22
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

This does not indicate that it is using the Proxy. Is that the issue here?

Comment: WHat is your ansible version?

Comment: Why do you place ProxyCommand into `ansible.cfg` and not to `.ssh/config` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your `ProxyCommand` syntax is correct and you want to include it in the `ansible.cfg`, the correct syntax would be to add an argument to the `ssh_args` in the `[ssh_connection]` section of the file:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ProxyCommand="nc -x 142.133.134.161:1088 %h %p"
```